# Remove color of camera scene in Android (SDK 19)

Tags: android, android-camera, augmented-reality, rajawali

I'm currently trying to put hands on Augmented Reality on Android (SDK 19) with Rajawali (OpenGL Framework). Creating 2D/3D objects and changing the camera scene color to red, green, etc. worked well so far. But now I want to use the possibility changing the camera scene color to display the camera scene in gray.

What I have so far:

```
public void setupCamera (int color) {
    ScreenQuad backgroundQuad = new ScreenQuad();
    Material cameraMaterial = new Material();

    cameraMaterial.setColor(color);
    cameraMaterial.setColorInfluence(1f);
    // We need to use Rajawali's {@code StreamingTexture} since it sets up the texture
    // for GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES rendering
    mCameraTexture =
            new StreamingTexture("camera", (StreamingTexture.ISurfaceListener) null);
    try {
        cameraMaterial.addTexture(mCameraTexture);
        backgroundQuad.setMaterial(cameraMaterial);
    } catch (ATexture.TextureException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception creating texture for RGB camera contents", e);
    }
    getCurrentScene().addChildAt(backgroundQuad, 0);
}
```

What I tried so far:

At first sight, it seemed that **.setColor(color)** expects an RGB value (in hex 0x00000000) whereas the first two bytes represent the alpha channel. But setting all values to something like this: 0x00666666 only lightens the camera scene up. Setting the value to 0x00ffffff makes the camera scene nearly white and 0x00000000 makes it only a little darker.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Without reading the code or knowing anything about Rajwali, just a guess: It may depends on the blending mode set, there are many different ways, how to blend two colours in OGL. Try to search for some docs, which blend mode is used, and if it is possible to change it?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your tip. I'll definitely go for it :)